# mergesort - with an insignificant change throws SystemInvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, arraylist, mergesort, bubble-sort

A very strange thing occured in my program. Here is the simplified code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
        numbers.Add(1);
        numbers.Add(3);
        numbers.Add(4);
        numbers.Add(2);

        var it = Sorts.MergeSort((ArrayList)numbers.Clone());
        Sorts.PrintArray(it, "mergesort");

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Sorts
{
    public static ArrayList BubbleSort(ArrayList numbers)
    {

        bool sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j < numbers.Count; j++)
            {
                if ((int)numbers[j - 1] > (int)numbers[j])
                {
                    int tmp = (int)numbers[j - 1];
                    numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = tmp;
                    sorted = false;
                }
            }
            if (sorted)
            {
                return numbers;
            }
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    public static ArrayList MergeSort(ArrayList numbers, int switchLimit = 3)
    {

        //if I use this if - everything works
        if (numbers.Count <= 1)
        {
           // return numbers;
        }

        //the moment I use this condition - it throws SystemInvalidOperationException in function Merge in the line of a "for"-loop
        if (numbers.Count <=switchLimit)
        {
              return Sorts.BubbleSort(numbers);
        }

        ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();
        int middle = numbers.Count / 2;

        ArrayList L = numbers.GetRange(0, middle);
        ArrayList R = numbers.GetRange(middle, numbers.Count - middle);
        L = MergeSort(L);
        R = MergeSort(R);

        return Merge(L, R);
    }

    private static ArrayList Merge(ArrayList L, ArrayList R)
    {

        ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();

        int l = 0;
        int r = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < L.Count + R.Count; i++)
        {
            if (l == L.Count)
            {
                ret.Add(R[r++]);

            }
            else if (r == R.Count)
            {
                ret.Add(L[l++]);
            }

            else if ((int)L[l] < (int)R[r])
            {
                ret.Add(L[l++]);
            }
            else
            {
                ret.Add(R[r++]);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static void PrintArray(ArrayList arr, string txt = "", int sleep = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{1}({0}): ", arr.Count, txt);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i].ToString().PadLeft(10));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep);
    }
}
```

There is a problem with my Sorts.MergeSort function.
When I use it normally (take a look at the first if-condition in a function - all works perfectly.
But the moment when I want it to switch to bubblesort with smaller input (the second if-condition in the function) it throws me an SystemInvalidOperationException. I have no idea where is the problem.
Do you see it?
Thanks. :)
Remark: bubblesort itself works - so there shouldn't be a problem in that sort...

Comment: Any reason you're using non-generic collections? We're not in 2004 :) Also, please give the full stack trace of the exception including the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your use of [`GetRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.getrange.aspx):

> This method does not create copies of the elements. The new ArrayList is only a view window into the source ArrayList. However, all subsequent changes to the source ArrayList must be done through this view window ArrayList. If changes are made directly to the source ArrayList, the view window ArrayList is invalidated and any operations on it will return an InvalidOperationException.

You're creating two views onto the original `ArrayList` and trying to work with both of them - but when one view modifies the underlying list, the other view is effectively invalidated.

If you change the code to create *copies* of the sublists - or if you work directly with the original list within specified bounds - then I believe it'll work fine.

(As noted in comments, I'd also *strongly* recommend that you use generic collections.)

Here's a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem you're running into:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.Add("a");
        list.Add("b");

        ArrayList view1 = list.GetRange(0, 1);
        ArrayList view2 = list.GetRange(1, 1);

        view1[0] = "c";
        Console.WriteLine(view2[0]); // Throws an exception
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a homework related question, so using generics at this stage might clash with his course layout. On the other hand adding generics to this exercise is a simple and effective way to get introduced to generics, and would rid the comparisons of the unsightly casts.

Comment: @Captain: I think it would be better to introduce generics than to teach people the non-generic collections. Ick!

Comment: That would be my opinion too, but many courses I have looked into (literature as well) does first the non-generic collections, than adds generics on top of that. Of course there are reasonable  arguments for both ways.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot. I guess I understand the underlying idea. I fix it by making copies by ArrayList L=((ArrayList)numbers.Clone()).GetRange(0, middle); and it worked but is slowed down the program a great deal. So I will rather work with the original list. Still, I have 2 questions: 1. why did the whole code work when I did't use the bubble sort? I still called the GetRange method and it worked correctly... 2. What generic collection would you recommend me to use instead of arraylist?(I found arraylist in the internet as a more confortable replacement of array - something like vector in c++

Comment: @Tomy: `List<T>` is by and large the generic equivalent of `ArrayList`. I don't know why it was working before - I'd have to look very closely at exactly what it was doing. It's possible that you had another bug which hid this one.

Answer (score 1):

on this line `R = MergeSort(R);` you alter the range of numbers represented by L. This invalidates L. Sorry I have to go so can't explain any further now.